# Golang NewRequest passing POST parameter to the API for testing

Tags: testing, go

This is my test method which creates a new request and passes POST param.

```
url1 := "/api/addprospect"
data := url.Values{}
data.Add("customer_name", "value")
b := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(data.Encode()))
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", serverHttp.URL+url1, b)
res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
```

The problem is the `POST param` is not getting picked up by the function handler of the url.

Can you please help me with setting up right request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly set the content-type header for your request.

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", serverHttp.URL+url1, b)

request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
```